# Import ResearchKit breaks my build for UnitTests

Tags: ios, cocoapods, researchkit

I am trying to use Research Kit in my iOS app (Xcode 8 and Swift 3), so I installed it using CocoaPods. Before that, I already had some Unit and UI tests.

I'm able to use Research Kit modules, but when I try to run all of my tests, the build fails. I noticed that this just happens with the Unit tests, not with the UI tests.

Some of the errors are:

- Include of non-modular header inside framework 'Researchkit.ORKVideoInstructionStep'
- Include of non-modular header inside framework 'Researchkit.ORKVideoCaptureStep'
- Duplicate interface definition
- Property has a previous declaration

This happens if I just use `import ResearchKit`. If I comment the import, the test builds successfully.

I already tried other solutions like checking the files are public and putting some script at the bottom of the Podfile but doesn't fix my problem.

EDIT: I removed ResearchKit and imported it again but directly with the Xcode folder from the repo, and this time my Unit tests build successfully.

Maybe it's a problem with Cocoapods? I did some research but I still can't solve this. Maybe I just have to use ResearchKit with the "Embedded Binaries" approach.

Comment: I had something similar and cleaning the build then building it again (Command + Shift + K to clean) fixed it. can you please try?

Comment: Hi @BashirSidani, thanks but It didn't work. The same amount of errors still appear.